# Is there a prop that can be used to ignore missing mandatory proptypes warnings?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I know this question may seems a little strange but I am trying to implement a skeleton loader. To do so, I would like to send my components a prop like "loading={true}" to tell them to ignore the others arguments as they won't need it (they only need to show they're loading, not to show anything meaningful)

I thought of a few workarounds :

- I could declare the proptypes as not required and simply declare a default value ... But then I wouldn't have any warning outside the loading step
- Just give some jumbo props for the mandatory props but that's a lot of useless code
- Duplicate every component - the "standard one" and the "loading one" but I have some rare corner cases where an element decide how many elements they show in javascript - based on the user's viewport that has to be duplicated too - alongside with doubling the files' volume for a loader.

This last idea seems the most promising as it would also prevent encumbering the components with additional conditions but I still would like to study the idea of letting the component manage their own render.

So, is there a way of telling Proptypes "hey, I know you don't have all the required props but trust me this one time but not the other times ?"

Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an optional shape.

It could look something like this; (consider as pseudo code)

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import MyComponent from 'somewhere';

const Example = ({ loading, options }) => (
  loading ? <div>Loading...</div> : <MyComponent {...options} />
);

Example.propTypes = {
  loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  options: PropTypes.oneOfType([null, PropTypes.shape({
    prop1: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  })]),
}

Example.defaultProps = {
  options: null,
}

export default Example;
```

Comment: Thank you ! Encapsulating the component to allow wrong props to be passed until the component is ready to render is really smart ! It doesn't, however, prevent me from creating a loader component for each component I want to encapsulate ... But I think this is likely the best answer and it adress the problem the way I put it. I'll take that as the accepted answer. Thanks again !

Comment: You could also just use a loading state while options object is null inside your components. No need to double up on components or files at all.